# vector class throwing an error after publishing the FLA for generating .ipa from flash cs5

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

I am creating a flash game for iPhone using Flash CS5, Everything runs smoothly when creating swf via Ctrl+Enter. But when i am attaching .p12 and provisioning profile files and publish the FLA for generating .ipa there is an error thrown by the compiler that is:

"Incorrect number of arguments, Expected no more than 0"

```
private static function closestVertexOnOBB(p:Vector, r:RectangleParticle):Vector   
{
        var d:Vector = p.minus(r.samp);         
        var q:Vector= new Vector(r.samp.x, r.samp.y);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 2; i++) 
        {
            var dist:Number = d.dot(r.axes[i]);

            if (dist >= 0) dist = r.extents[i];
            else if (dist < 0) dist = -r.extents[i];

            q.plusEquals(r.axes[i].mult(dist));
        }
        return q;
}
```

can anyone help please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vector class is actually a native flash class since Flash Player 10 (API docs) and is therefore a class-name so should avoid for our custom classes. we should have different class name rather than the inbuilt flash keywords and class names.:)